# Как пишутся интерфейсы с 0?

Tags: gui, интерфейс

Есть примитивы Windows на основании которых можно построить примитивное UI.
Есть множество UI фреймворков, которые позволяют сделать более крутые интерфейсы.

Что лежит в основе всего этого добр?

Представим, что нету никаких фреймворков и нужно пилить GUI с 0. Что бы мне пришло в этом случае на помощь?

Вопрос, наверное, слишком общий, но интересны общие черты- способы создания UI без готовых примитивов.

Comment: это называется компьютерная графика

Comment: В Windows понадобился бы WinAPI. В других операционных системах API той графической подсистемы, которая используется.

Answer (score 1):

На самом низком уровне вы командуете железу, чтобы оно зажгло на мониторе пиксель. Управлять этим можно вне операционной системы, с помощью ассемблера, или двоичного кода. Далее идет следующий уровень абстракции: операционная система со встроенными примитивами и программными интерфейсами. Она умеет управлять драйверами, которые в свою очередь командют видеокарте, где и как рисовать пиксели. Т.е. по сути ОС - это прослойка между "фреймворками" и железом. Далее идут "фреймворки", которые работают через единый интерфейс операционной системы.

Таким образом, если вы желаете "с нуля" писать интерфейс, или графику - то вам имеет смысл разобраться с графическим программным интерфейсом ОС, под которую вы хотите это делать.

Comment: или писать на OpenGL, он более менее кросс-платформенный

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, ну т.е всякие фотошопы скорее всего на OpenGL рисуют интерфейс свой?

Comment: @WhatMan не скажу за фотошопы, но высока верятность. для графических-игровых приложений приходилось лопатить кнопочки и формочки на opengl

Comment: @StrangerintheQ и на сколько это низкоуровневое? Или там сплошная геометрия и нету каких-нибудь готовых способов, например понять наведен ли курсор на примитив и т д?

Comment: @WhatMan да для сложных сцен приходится применять трюки для этого, вроде picking buffer http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/ru/miscellaneous/clicking-on-objects/picking-with-an-opengl-hack/

Comment: @WhatMan но вы сами быстренько смастерите себе высокоуровневое апи

Comment: @WhatMan, у фотошопа даже собственная реализация файла подкачки. Не думаю, что они стали бы использовать OpenGL. Впрочем, кто ж их знает.

Comment: @WhatMan https://helpx.adobe.com/ru/photoshop/kb/gpu-opengl-features-preferences-photoshop.html

Comment: @Qwertiy не логично. Ведь если они на низкоуровневом уровне что-то пилили бы, то им бы пришлось под каждое новое поколение что-то пилить. А так, они спрятались за OpenGL и не нужно пилить одновременно отрисовку под NVidia и AMD +если в новом поколении, что-то оптимизировали под OpenGL производители видеокарт, то автоматом фотошоп будет шустрее работать без переписывания чего-либо.

Comment: @WhatMan, вроде бы DirectX лучше OpenGL? Или ошибаюсь?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, а можешь пояснить? А то я не понимаю ссылку.

Comment: @Qwertiy DirectX, хоть и лучше но это windows

Comment: @Qwertiy ну по ссылке, как я понял, OpenGL упоминается => возможно фотошоп на его базе построен

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну может быть с приходом .Net Core 3.0 что-то изменится, ведь он кросс платформенный, а там хотели десктоп добавить, типа WPF, а сам по себе WPF рендерится через DirectX => если будет кроссплатформа, то не выгодно 2 разных рендера поддерживать=> может быть DirectX выпустят. Правда, это ударит по популярности Windows, ведь у многих он стоит дома за счет большого спектра игр.

Comment: @WhatMan, а разве там не операции, применимые к редактируемому файлу описаны?